Touch pad pinch zoom
I am newbie to Ubuntu,  and a low visioner.  I am facing problems in zooming a webpage of chrome, like in windows chrome I can zoom a webpage by two fingers ( bring close and far ) . But it is not working in linux .please help.

Providing your Ubuntu product & release details will help us to better help you. It sounds like you're asking about Ubuntu Desktop, but being specific and providing release details (which will tell us what version of GNOME you're using) is helpful.
